# jQuery Autocomplete list hidden under the div underneath

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, frontend

I have a `<section>` tag containing two main divs. The upper div wraps an `input` to which a jQuery autocomplete widget is assigned. However, the autocomplete list shows under the lower div, making it useless.

I have already tried setting the `z-index` of both the input and the div to the value that would make it visible, applying the `!important` annotation, but nothing seems to work. What could be the reason?

Is this really an issue with the `z-index`? Note that the bottom div contains a widget with animations (drop down menu), if it has any relevance to the problem.

These are the solutions that I tried:

- [autocomplete suggestion list wrong z-index, how can i change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764710/autocomplete-suggestion-list-wrong-z-index-how-can-i-change)
- [jQuery autocomplete suggestion box hidden behind Bootstrap Nav bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47398178/jquery-autocomplete-suggestion-box-hidden-behind-bootstrap-nav-bar)
- [jQuery AutoComplete displaying behind elements after first use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676217/jquery-autocomplete-displaying-behind-elements-after-first-use)

Here's a code that use to fix it, to no avail:

```
//top div
.tag-filtering-input{
    z-index: 4000 !important;
}
//bottom div
.categories-container{
    z-index: 3000;
}
```

Comment: We cannot help you without seeing the relevant HTML/JS/CSS which causes this behaviour